# "$watch"ing a service doesn't appear to update reliably

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am currently building a simple drag & drop directive so that I can move some SVG stuff around on the screen.  At the moment I'm still in the early stages, but I have run into a strange issue with $watch that I'm hoping someone can help me with.

I have a service that maintains my mouse state.  At the moment it's just the x and y coordinates of the cursor.  I also have an attribute level directive that interacts with this service in order to bind to the mouse-move event and update the service whenever someone moves the mouse around.  These two items work together like a champ.  The directive keeps the service up to date with the mouse's position and since my service (Factory really) is a singleton, I can pull this data in to other directives/controllers to see what's going on with the mouse.

Here's the problem:  I'm trying to allow a specific SVG element to be dragged around, so I created a super simple controller with two functions:  a "trackDrag" function that begins tracking and moving a specific element, and a "releaseDrag" which stops tracking/moving the element (drops it where it is, basically).

Inside of my trackDrag function, I attempt to use $scope.$watch to watch the mouse service's current x and y coordinates.  Since it's a factory, these values are returned in a function and my watch looks something like this:

```
$scope.$watch("mouseTrackingService.get()", function(){
     // do some stuff here
});
```

This watch DOES fire off when I first start dragging an element but it doesn't fire as I continue dragging it across the screen.  In my "releaseDrag" function, I deallocate the watcher and that seems to work correctly.  I'm kind of stumped about why I don't see the watch fire off continuously, even though I can console write out inside of the service and I see that IT is updating correctly.

I've included a plnkr with some sample code below:
http://plnkr.co/edit/g3WEgiQWvd9oXCpFEByn?p=preview

If I just give in and use a $interval then this code works (updating the position every 10ms for example), but really I see that as a much less "angular" way of doing things vs binding.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I'm just being dumb.  I forgot that $scope.$watch can ONLY WATCH SCOPE VARIABLES.

I fixed this issue by adding the following wrapper around the service:

```
 $scope.currentMouse = function(){
        return mouseTrackingService.get();
    };
```

I can then watch currentMouse:

```
$scope.$watch(currentMouse(), function(){
             updateMousePosition(target);
             console.log("noticed a change");
        });
```

Of course that gives me that awful Digest error after more than like a half second of dragging:
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
But that's a different issue entirely.

Sorry folks, nothing to see here.  Move along now :-p

Comment: Thats correct but you don't have to assign the watch function which returns the service to the `$scope` instead you can pass the function directly to the `$watch`.